# How to add jdk17 in Docker run command in amazon extras in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, amazon-linux-extras

I am trying to use the amazon linux and installing amazon extras,
Here is my Dockerfile,

```bash
FROM amazonlinux:2

# Install CloudHSM client
RUN yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudhsmv2-software/CloudHsmClient/EL7/cloudhsm-client-3.4.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

# Install CloudHSM Java library
RUN yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudhsmv2-software/CloudHsmClient/EL7/cloudhsm-client-jce-3.4.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

# Install Java 11
RUN amazon-linux-extras install -y java-openjdk11

When I replace the run command with following 
RUN amazon-linux-extras install -y java-openjdk17
It fails, I get error as java-openjdk17 not found. Please help.


# Install Java 11
RUN amazon-linux-extras install -y java-openjdk11
```

When I replace the run command with following

```bash
RUN amazon-linux-extras install -y java-openjdk17
```

It fails, I get error as java-openjdk17 not found. Please help.

Comment: Consider using an JDK 17 base image, like [eclipse-temurin:17-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/eclipse-temurin/17-alpine/images/sha256-1451b2df3a00e2ab14c4c63c6c9f8211c318f450954971bb8763bb100ce248c1?context=explore)

Answer (score 0):

You can update install to this

```
RUN amazon-linux-extras install -y java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64
```